# How to Filter views result by current logged in user's role

Tags: views

I know it can be done using PHP Code I am looking an option which will be using configurations.

Comment: [D7 - Filter a view based on current user's roles?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/98551/d7-filter-a-view-based-on-current-users-roles), [filter criteria: current users role](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/12209/filter-criteria-current-users-role), [Drupal7 - Filter view based on current user's roles?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840490/drupal7-filter-view-based-on-current-users-roles)

Comment: Thanks but all provided links suggest to use PHP Code in views UI.

Comment: hook_views_query_alter() will help in not using php in views ui but in custom code.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding view relationship to "Content: Author", and then add contextual filter for field "(author) User: Roles".

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

[Can you filter views user list result based on the current users role](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/80020/can-you-filter-views-user-list-result-based-on-the-current-users-role)

Answer (score 0):

Currently logged-in user can be achieved by using `global variable`

```
<?php

global $user;

if (in_array('administrator', $user->roles)) {
        // do something
}
```

Comment: The OP doesn't want to use PHP.